# Prometheus Operator scrape_interval for custom metrics in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, prometheus-operator, prometheus-adapter

I have defined a custom metric in my application via a [Gauge](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#gauge). I have then exposed this metric via port 9090 on all Pods for the Deployment for Prometheus to scrape.

I can gather these custom metrics just fine, but how do I change the `scrape_interval` for this single metric?

I think I might need to add a job to the `additionalScrapeConfigs` in the Prometheus Operator's `prometheus-config.yaml`.

1. Is this the correct way to add a `scrape_interval` to a custom metric?
2. If it is, how should my `scrape_config` look to gather the metrics from any replica of this deployment?

These are the configurations I've tried, but neither of them seem to work:

```yaml
# 1
- job_name: 'my-super-cool-app-requests'
  scrape_interval: 200ms
  scrape_timeout: 190ms
  static_configs:
     - targets:
        # I don't think this is right as my pod name isn't exactly "my-super-cool-app"
        # as it has a hash at the end "my-super-cool-app-hx728".
        # FYI the service does not expose 9090 for prometheus, only the pod.
        # so I couldn't do "my-super-cool-app.super-cool-ns.svc:9090"
        - my-super-cool-app.super-cool-ns.pod:9090
```

```yaml
# 2
- job_name: 'my-super-cool-app-requests'
  scrape_interval: 200ms
  scrape_timeout: 190ms
  metrics_path: /apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/super-cool-ns/metrics/my-custom-metric-name
```